# Why am I able to redirect back to the login component even though I'm authenticated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

Upon entering my credentials, I successfully can redirect to the `<Gallery/>` component.  However, once on the `<Gallery/>` component, if I want to switch from `/gallery` to `/`, I shouldn't be able to unless I logout (that of which I haven't implemented, yet) but unfortunately - I'm able to and I'm not sure why.

My question is: How's this happening and how can I remain on `/gallery` even if I manually go to my browser's search bar and switch my path to `/` which's the `<Login/>` component?  I think something might be off with my `<ProtectedRoute/>` but I'm unsure.

Here's `App.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LoginSignUp from "./LoginSignUp/LoginSignUp";
import Gallery from "./Gallery/Gallery";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute/ProtectedRoute";

function App() {

    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginSignUp} />
                <ProtectedRoute component={Gallery} path='/gallery'/>
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}

if (document.getElementById("main")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Router><App/></Router>, document.getElementById("main"));
}
```

Here's `ProtectedRoute.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import {Redirect, Route, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
    const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log("this", isAuthenticated);

    return (
        <Route
            {...restOfProps}
            render={(props) =>
                isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/' />
            }
        />
    );
}
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: you need to handle this behavior in the `LoginSignUp` component. You need to redirect to `Gallery` if the authentication is done.

Comment: @Thinker gotcha, but how do I ensure that `Gallery`'s a protected route and that you simply cannot navigate to `/` (`<Login/>` component) if you manually changed the URLs file path?

Comment: on a high level, in `LoginSignUp` componentDidMount, check if there is a value for `token` in localstorage. If yes, then do this.props.navigation.navigate('Gallery')